# How to use multiple optional parameters in C#

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I have a method like this:

```
public static void MyMethod(int a, String opt1 = null, byte[] opt2 = null)
{
//code 
}
```

I want to call MyMeythod once using opt1, and once using opt2;

`MyMethod(3,"param");` call worked but

`MyMethod(3,new byte[]);` doesn't compile

Is there a way to do this or should I pass opt1 explicitly null

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments in your case `MyMethod(a: 3, opt2: new byte[]);`

Comment: In C# 7.3 you can write: `MyMethod(opt2: new byte[] { }, a: 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the name:

```
MyMethod(3, opt2: new byte[]);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7.3 you can also use another ordering:

```
MyMethod(opt2: new byte[] { }, a: 3)
```

Comment: Alright Thank you!

Comment: @JamalSalman You're welcome!